# Retrieve unicode character values from oracle 11g database

Tags: sql, database, unicode, oracle11g, data-retrieval

I have an oracle 11g database in which i have a table with column as `varchar2(200 byte)`.In this table i am storing unicode and also latin characters and i want to retrieve only the values with unicode characters.
How can i do this using sql?

Comment: The only way to extract unicode characters is to use those in where clause.

Comment: How can i do that? I dont know the characters upfront to  use them in where clause.Do i need regex for that if yes please let me know the regex to identify unicode characters.